# Answers is crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7, crashlytics

I'm trying to use Answers, the framework inside Crashlytics to track events.
When I try to run it, it crashes.

At the top:

```
import Fabric
import Crashlytics
```

Then further down in app delegate:

```
 Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])
 Fabric.with([Answers()])
```

And finally I do:

```
Answers.logCustomEventWithName("test", customAttributes: ["test1":"a"])
```

And it throws an exception:

```
[CLSAnalyticsController logCustomEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa061d356c0
2015-09-15 19:29:02.210 TestApp[80248:5943964] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CLSAnalyticsController logCustomEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa061d356c0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Any ideas what's going on?

I tried removing Crashlytics and reinstalling, and no luck. Is this an Xcode/ios9 problem, perhaps?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do :

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.sharedInstance()])
```

instead of

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the Fabric initialisation inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Also Crashlytics setup tells me to use the following init code that includes `.self()`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])

}
```

Comment: yes doing this, but still crashes after I try to log an event =/